# Javascript/Node.js: How to define a local variable as part of arguments in a function call?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

Often, I define and call a function like this - particularly when we use flags:

```
function cat(doMeon, doCloseEyes)
{
  if (doMeon) console.log("Meon...");
  if (doCloseEyes) console.log("Hmm, I closed my eyes..."); 
}
...
// And then call, using flags. Names are temporary, only for readability
cat(doMeon=true, doCloseEyes=true);
```

Note that we could just do "cat(true, true)" but that kills the readability.

But the problem this introduces is that the two variables are now in global scope. And we shouldn't polluting the global scope. But we can't do this:

```
// Doesn't work...
cat(var doMeon=true, var doCloseEyes=true);
```

Is there an approach that one can use as best practice here? (Note: Defining these vars outside is not such a good idea.)

Comment: Where/how did you pick up that `func(foo=true)` style of invocation as a common practice? Are you trying to emulate another language?

Comment: You're describing is named parameters, which JavaScript doesn't have.

Comment: Javascript values are passed by position, not name. You can't do `cat(var x)` because it's a syntax error—the keyword *var* is a [reserved word](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1) and can't be used where an identifier or expression is expected (*var* can only be used in a variable statement, which isn't an expression).

Comment: While Python can do this, _MANY_ other language simply pass parameters by position. If you think this "kills the readability", maybe you could re-think of your coding and reading style.

Comment: I already said that it is wrong. We can't use "var" in params; perhaps javascript should allow that. And you can't just do "cat(true, true)" - it is so unreadable. What practice do you adopt in the above situation?

Comment: BTW, positioning of parameters is not an issue or topic of discussion here.

Answer (score 2):

One method to pass in arguments with readability would be to pass an object containing each argument as a named property:

i.e.

```
cat({
    doMeon: true,
    doCloseEyes: true
});
```

And inside the function, you can do:

```
function cat(_props) {
    if (_props.doMeon) console.log("Meon...");
    if (_props.doCloseEyes) console.log("Hmm, I closed my eyes..."); 
    ....
}
```

Comment: I am inclined to categorize this as 'Next best approach', because we end up creating an object. It just occurred to me - why not just use name as well as flag as arguments (and ignore the name part in the function), something like: "cat("doMeon", true, "doCloseEyes", true);"...  After all, I am only looking for convention.

Comment: @uniwalker - Yes, but it would mean creating several objects instead of one (each string is an object). Not an issue if they are unnamed arguments, they'll be popped off the call stack and gc'd (sooner or later) once the function completes execution.

Comment: @techfoobar Local variables in javascript functions do not get gc'd even after the completion of the parent function execution but they will continue to reside in memory as long as they continue to exist in the closure of some function. But I do not know what happens to the "arguments" object. Are you sure it gets gc'd with function completion ?

Comment: @AksharPrabhuDesai - The argument values do get popped of the stack (like in all other langs as well) with the function once execution is done. The `arguments` variable will probably have some value as long as its not in the outermost scope.

Comment: @techfoobar No. It turns out that the argument objects too are treated like normal variables and continue to remain available as long as there are have any scope chain links. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2Kv3y/ . I thought you were suggesting otherwise.

Comment: @AksharPrabhuDesai - Ofcourse the function is not gc'd. I meant the unreferenced arguments. For example, if we call `foo(a, b)` as `foo(5, "Hello")`, then the `5` and the `"Hello"` will be popped off the stack once foo finishes executing. Same with any local variables defined inside `foo()`. But the function `foo()` itself will not be gc'd as its still callable within the scope where its defined..

Comment: I expect the constant strings to be managed elsewhere on heap and only pointers used as part of arguments list. Isn't it? The constants (including function definitions) can be removed from heap only if good amount of static analysis can be done by V8.

Answer (score 0):

You could create two functions instead:

```
function catDoMeon()
{
  console.log("Meon...");
}

function catDoCloseEyes()
{
  console.log("Hmm, I closed my eyes..."); 
}

catDoMeon();
catDoCloseEyes();
```

Comment: Agree, but looking for a standard practice independent of application semantics.

Comment: @uniwalker This is a good practice actually; each of those flags is tied to a branch in your code, so it's better to separate them.